# Process terminates when function is called

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to write a function that will read and print the contents of a file. I gave the filename as a parameter for my function. I used `FILE *testfile` to create a file handle and then I use `fread` to read the file. `block_t` is a struct and `nreserved` are the reserved segments of the block. Each block has records. I don't think that it is necessary to tell you how `block_t` is created.

My problem is that even though the function runs and I can see in the console the results that I want to see the process terminates. This happens even if I comment out the if else parts. I get this message `Process terminated with status -1073741510`

Here is my code:

```
#include "dbtproj.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void showEntriesOfBlock(char *filename){
    FILE *testfile;
    block_t block;
    int nreserved;


    //open file and print contents
    testfile = fopen(filename,"r");

    if(testfile==NULL)
        cout << "Error";
    else{
        while(!feof(testfile)){
            fread(&block, 1, sizeof(block_t), testfile);
            nreserved = block.nreserved;

    //print block contents
    for (int i=0; i<nreserved; ++i) {
        printf("this is block id: %d, record id: %d, num: %d, str: %s\n",
                block.blockid, block.entries[i].recid, block.entries[i].num,
                block.entries[i].str);
        }
    }
}
fclose(testfile);
};
```

In my main file I create a file by using `outfile = fopen("file.bin", "w");` then I write random data to the file. Then I close the file with `fclose(outfile);` and in the next line I call my function like this `showEntriesOfBlock("file.bin");`

Can anybody help? I think that I might have messed up my pointers of did something wrong with the file handlers.

This is how I give data to my blocks and records.

```
for (int b=0; b<nblocks; ++b) { // for each block

    block.blockid = b;
    for (int r=0; r<MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK; ++r) { // for each record

        // prepare a record
        record.recid = recid++;
        record.num = rand() % 1000;
        strcpy(record.str,"hello");   // put the same string to all records
        record.valid = true;

        memcpy(&block.entries[r], &record, sizeof(record_t)); // copy record to block
    }

    block.nreserved = MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK;
    block.valid = true;

    fwrite(&block, 1, sizeof(block_t), outfile);    // write the block to the file
}

fclose(outfile);
```

And here are the definitions of my structs:

```
// This is the definition of a record of the input file. Contains three fields, recid,           num and str
typedef struct {
    unsigned int recid;
    unsigned int num;
    char str[STR_LENGTH];
    bool valid;  // if set, then this record is valid
 } record_t;


// This is the definition of a block, which contains a number of fixed-sized records
typedef struct {
    unsigned int blockid;
    unsigned int nreserved; // how many reserved entries
    record_t entries[MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK]; // array of records
    bool valid;  // if set, then this block is valid
    unsigned char misc;
    unsigned int next_blockid;
    unsigned int dummy;
} block_t;
```

Comment: Step through the program in a debugger and you'll probably see that it crashes in the printf line.

Comment: You can't read and write structs as binary dumps like that. You need to manually read/write each field.

Comment: `while (!eof())` is wrong. Do `while (fread(&block, 1, sizeof(block_t), testfile))`.

Comment: How do you write random data to the file?  You can use fread to read it, but it's good practice to match that with fwrite, since both work on binary data- if you're writing text, it might be interpreting that as binary and not finding a null terminator on the string you're reading.

Comment: The same code that I use in the function runs fine in the main. It was written by my professor as an example.

Comment: Professors write some of the worst code I've ever seen.

Comment: It might be bad code but it works as a template for a project and i can't use anything else. I would prefer to use 'fstream' to work on files but I can't change it.

Comment: `fwrite(&block, 1, sizeof(block_t), outfile);` this is bad. Compilers might put different padding between data members or have different sizes. Code created by a different compiler, or even the same compiler with different options, cannot reliably read this data. Tell your professor. Maybe he can learn to teach new students better.

Comment: FILE* and fread + friends are all from C. You should upgrade to the C++ standard equivalents. They are easier to use and a bit clearer (IMO.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version using FILE* (which I wouldn't recommend if you're learning...)

NOTE: open your files in binary mode : fopen(filename, "wb") or fopen(filename, "rb")

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>

const int STR_LENGTH = 10;
const int MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK = 5;

//! For my test I assumed the following definitions.
//! (i.e. that block_t is a POD.)
// This is the definition of a record of the input file. Contains three fields, recid,           num and str
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int recid;
    unsigned int num;
    char str[STR_LENGTH];
    bool valid;  // if set, then this record is valid
} record_t;


// This is the definition of a block, which contains a number of fixed-sized records
typedef struct 
{
    unsigned int blockid;
    unsigned int nreserved; // how many reserved entries
    record_t entries[MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK]; // array of records
    bool valid;  // if set, then this block is valid
    unsigned char misc;
    unsigned int next_blockid;
    unsigned int dummy;
} block_t;

void showEntriesOfBlock(const char *filename)
{
    FILE* testfile = fopen(filename, "rb");
    assert(testfile);

    if (!testfile)
    {
        perror("Error");
        return;
    }

    block_t block;                
    while(fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&block), sizeof(block_t), 1, testfile))
    {
        if (ferror(testfile))
        {
            perror("Error while reading");
            return;
        }

        //print block contents
        for (int i = 0; i < block.nreserved; ++i)
        {
            printf("this is block id: %d, record id: %d, num: %d, str: %s\n",
                block.blockid, block.entries[i].recid, block.entries[i].num,
                block.entries[i].str);
        }
    }

    fclose(testfile);
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::string filename = "g:/test.dat";
    FILE* outfile;
    outfile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "wb");
    int nblocks = 10;
    int recid = 0;

    for (int b = 0; b < nblocks; ++b)
    {
        block_t block;
        block.blockid = b;
        for (int r = 0; r < MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK; ++r)
        {
            // for each record
            // prepare a record
            record_t record;
            record.recid = recid++;
            record.num = rand() % 1000;
            strcpy(record.str, "hello");   // put the same string to all records
            record.valid = true;

            memcpy(&block.entries[r], &record, sizeof(record_t)); // copy record to block
        }

        block.nreserved = MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK;
        block.valid = true;

        fwrite(&block, sizeof(block_t), 1, outfile);    // write the block to the file
    }

    fclose(outfile);

    showEntriesOfBlock(filename.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <type_traits>

void showEntriesOfBlock(char *filename)
{
    std::ifstream testfile(filename, std::ios_base::binary);
    assert(testfile);

    if (!testfile)
    {
        std::cout << "Error";
        return;
    }

    block_t block;
    int nreserved;

    while (testfile)
    {
        //! This assumes block is a POD.
        static_assert(std::is_pod<block_t>::value, "block_t is not a POD.");
        testfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&block), sizeof(block_t));
        nreserved = block.nreserved;

        //print block contents
        for (int i = 0; i < nreserved; ++i) 
        {
            printf("this is block id: %d, record id: %d, num: %d, str: %s\n",
                    block.blockid, block.entries[i].recid, block.entries[i].num,
                    block.entries[i].str);
        }        
    }

    testfile.close();
};
```

Comment: If you are going C++ route, why not make filename const char *?

Comment: You don't open your filestream in binary mode.

Comment: `testfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&block), sizeof(block_t));` I'm not 100% sure this is bad if block is a POD, but my hunch tells me it is.

Comment: The binary mode is a good point (I'll add it), but I think if you only call read, it won't matter in this case.

Comment: If newlines contain 2 chars on the system, and struct data has them in it, it would read as only `\n`, wouldn't it?

Comment: If block_t is a POD, then it has a contiguous memory layout of constant size. That means you can read sizeof(block_t) bytes into memory and then view that memory as a block_t instance.

Comment: Assuming that its data members are the same size. Eg is long 32 or 64 bits?